# .m file to executable file in linux to run in another linux machine

Tags: linux, matlab

Hi I am working in matlab linux. I want to convert my .m files to .exe or some executable file so that I can run it in another linux machine.I tried doing 
    mcc -m filename.m -o newfile
But it creates run_newfile.sh and newfile.o files. How do I sonvert this .sh file to .exe or how can I run this .sh file in other machine. please help

solved:
I solved the problem . I used 
mcc -mv filename.m

command which creates a executable file and the I can run the executable file which has same name with the .m file as
./filename

in the shell . And also we need to check if the MCR is installed or not. if not we need to install the MCR. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Linux doesn't use .exe files.

Comment: You could use the `-c` option to generate C code and compile it on the windows machine?

Comment: I do not want to compile to in window machine..I want to execute in linux but in other machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the created files on other linux machines by `sh run_newfile.sh`. You cannot create exe-files for windows machines on linux machines. For creating windows-executable Exe-Files you have to use a windows machine.

Comment: If the run_newfile.sh runs its ok I do not need .exe file I want to run it in linux machine only..but the problem is when I try to do sh run in the same machine it give out put as follows"------------------------------------------
Usage:
run_hobe.sh <deployedMCRroot> args"

Comment: take a look a this article: 
http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use MATLAB Compiler to produce Windows executables (.exe files), you must run it on a Windows machine. If you run it on a Linux machine it will produce outputs suitable for Linux, as you're seeing.

Your MATLAB license is cross-platform and you may install it multiple times, so you can install it on Windows as well as Linux (so long as you don't use more than two of the multiple installations simultaneously).

If you don't have the install files for Windows, than so long as your license is in maintenance you can download them by logging in to your MathWorks account.

Comment: I want to make executable file in linux which will run in linux but other machine...I do not want to run it in window

Comment: Well, from your question it sounds like you've done that. Take the `.sh` file and the other outputs of the compilation, put them on the new machine along with the MCR, and it should run. If that isn't working, you need to elaborate your question with more details about what exactly is going wrong. And perhaps remove the part that refers to `.exe` files, which are for Windows.

Comment: Hi, Before taking them to other m/c I was trying to test in the same linux m/c if it runs well but when I do sh run it give out put as follows"------------------------------------------ Usage: run_hobe.sh <deployedMCRroot> args"